# Scala Iterator with Map and For

Tags: scala, dictionary, iterator, for-loop, scala-collections

Given:

```
val list = List("one","two","three")     
val it = list.toIterator
```

I can run:

```
list map ("_" +) -> List(_one, _two, _three)
for (i <- list) yield("_" + i) -> List(_one, _two, _three)
```

If I run the same on the iterator I get:

```
it map ("_" + ) -> Iterator[java.lang.String] = empty iterator
for (i <- it) yield("_" + i) -> Iterator[java.lang.String] = empty iterator
```

Shouldn't I get back another (non-empty) Iterator[String] after I run map/for on it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
scala> def ints(n: Int): Stream[Int] = n #:: ints(n + 1)
ints: (n: Int)Stream[Int]

scala> val list = List("one","two","three")
list: List[java.lang.String] = List(one, two, three)

scala> val it = list.toIterator
it: Iterator[java.lang.String] = non-empty iterator

scala> it map ("_" + )
res24: Iterator[java.lang.String] = non-empty iterator

scala> it map ("_" + )
res25: Iterator[java.lang.String] = non-empty iterator

scala> for (i <- it) yield("_" + i)
res26: Iterator[java.lang.String] = non-empty iterator
```

Maybe you used your iterator?

```
scala> res26.foreach{println}
_one
_two
_three

scala> res26
res28: Iterator[java.lang.String] = empty iterator
```

Since iterators are stateful and not resettable, once you used it, it is empty and can't be used again.

Instead, you can use views:

```
scala> val v = list.view
v: java.lang.Object with scala.collection.SeqView[java.lang.String,List[java.lang.String]] = SeqView(one, two, three)

scala> v map ("_" + )
res29: scala.collection.SeqView[java.lang.String,Seq[_]] = SeqViewM(...)

scala> for (i <- v) yield("_" + i)
res30: scala.collection.SeqView[java.lang.String,Seq[_]] = SeqViewM(...)

scala> res29.foreach{println}
_one
_two
_three

scala> res29
res32: scala.collection.SeqView[java.lang.String,Seq[_]] = SeqViewM(...)

scala> res29.foreach{println}
_one
_two
_three
```

Comment: You're right! I must have used the Iterator before I ran up the examples. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

See [Iterators](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_43.html).

> There's an important difference between the `foreach` method on iterators and the same method on traversable collections: When called to an iterator, `foreach` will leave the iterator at its end when it is done. So calling `next` again on the same iterator will fail with a `NoSuchElementException`. By contrast, when called on on a collection, `foreach` leaves the number of elements in the collection unchanged (unless the passed function adds to removes elements, but this is discouraged, because it may lead to surprising results).

...

> As you can see, after the call to `it.map`, the `it` iterator has advanced to its end.